# How to order by key (alphabetically) in defaultdict(list) for an inverted index

Tags: python, sorting, defaultdict

I have an inverted index. It consists of my word dictionary and the posting list of documents in which the terms appear. What I simply want is to sort my dictionary alphabetically. This is how it looks right now (example):

```
self.index = 
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {
'all': [['d03', array('I', [32L, 40L)], ['d07', array('I', [32L, 40L, 47L])], ['d05', array('I', [32L, 40L, 47L])]],
'just': [['d03', array('I', [11L])], ['d07', array('I', [11L])], ['d05', array('I', [11L])], ['d08', array('I', [11L])]])
'collect': [['d04', array('I', [24L])]]
'occurring': [['d03', array('I', [34L])], ['d07', array('I', [34L])]
```

...and so on
this is how it should look like after sorting:

```
'all': [['d03', array('I', [32L, 40L)], ['d07', array('I', [32L, 40L, 47L])], ['d05', array('I', [32L, 40L, 47L])]],
'collect': [['d04', array('I', [24L])]]
'just': [['d03', array('I', [11L])], ['d07', array('I', [11L])], ['d05', array('I', [11L])], ['d08', array('I', [11L])]])
'occurring': [['d03', array('I', [34L])], ['d07', array('I', [34L])]
```

what i tried:

```
self.index = sorted(self.index)
print self.index
print self.index['all']
```

the first print call delivers a perfect sorted list of words but if I try to get the connected postinglist for the word 'all', I receive this error message:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `sorted()` on a dictionary returns just a list of the *keys* in sorted order. Dictionaries themselves have no inherent order, you cannot sort those.

Because you re-assigned the output of `sorted()` back to `self.index`, you've now lost your reference to the original `defaultdict`.

Comment: yep. IMHO calling sorted() is better for viewing results in an ordered way instead of reordering data. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe dictionaries can be sorted in the sense you are referring to. If you want to *view* the dictionary sorted you can try the following:

```
sorted(self.index.items())
```

Note however that the result is not a dictionary - its just a list of (key, value) tuples which would be associated with each other in the original dictionary.

Comment: This is just `sorted(self.index.items())` - no need to zip the keys and values

Comment: Thanks Jon, updated my post accordingly :) Forgot about items() for a second. Interestingly though, if you want to sort by value rather than by key, I think you would have to resort to zip(self.index.values(), self.index.keys())

Comment: Well, that's one way... but the other would be to provide a key argument to sorted, eg: `sorted(self.index.items(), key=lambda L: L[1])` - that way it retains the key/value order... Otherwise, you'd have to reverse the items of the result back after...

Answer (score 1):

I read this yesterday and i think it might be just what you are looking for. Its a Binary Heap implementation for Python dictionaries. It puts out its items in sorted order if you call a for on it.

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/117228-priority-dictionary/